# Remover arquivo JS via JS

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, jsp

Tenho um site que possui o menu lateral fixo e a outra parte é carregada as paginas. Para cada página do site eu fiz um arquivo js. Por exemplo: Home.jsp eu tenho o arquivo home.js, Contatos.jsp eu tenho o contatos.js.

Eu estou carregando as páginas com o comando jquery `.load('Home.jsp')`. O que acontece é que quando eu abro a pagina Home, os arquivos são carregados normalmente, porém quando eu abro a Contatos, o js da Home da conflito com o js da Contatos. O conflito ocorre pois existem funções com mesmo nome, porém imaginava que ao sobrepor uma página com a outra o js da antiga iria ser "apagado".

Alguém sabe se via JS eu consigo efetivamente apagar um arquivo JS do browser? Ou se tenho que limpar algum cache, ou algo parecido.

Exemplo:

**Menu.jsp:**

```
<div>
    <div id="home">Home</div>
    <div id="contato">Contatos</div>
</div>
```

**menu.js**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     $("#home").click(function(){
         //.dconteudo è uma div onde jogo as páginas que serão exibida no site 
         $(".dconteudo").load("home.jsp")
     });

     $("#contato").click(function(){
         //.dconteudo è uma div onde jogo as páginas que serão exibida no site 
         $(".dconteudo").load("contato.jsp")
     });
});
```

**Home.jsp**

```
....
<head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="home.js"></script>
</head>...
```

**Contato.jsp**

```
....
<head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="contato.js"></script>
</head>...
```

**home.js**

```
function carregaFundo(){
     $("#fundo").show(200);
}
```

**contato.js**

```
function carregaFundo(){
     $("#fundo").show(200);
}
```

Quando eu chamo o home.jsp e depois o contato.jsp, ao carregar o contato.jsp, a função carregaFundo() é chamada duas vezes, ou seja, uma vez para o arquivo home.js e outra para o arquivo contato.js

Comment: Se puder explicar melhor o problema que tem em concreto e, se possível, mostrar código que já tenha feito onde se encontre esse problema. Está demasiado ampla a sua pergunta, veja na [Central de Ajuda Como Perguntar](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Estranho rodar duas vezes... Se a função é redefinida, deveria rodar uma vez só. Tem algum link de exemplo funcional para a gente ver?

Comment: @bfavaretto Não tenho como publicar nenhum exemplo. Mas também achava que a função seria redefinida e não teria problema. Mas quando olho na Ferramenta de Desenvolvimento, eu consigo acessar os dois JS. Mesmo "retirando" a outra página com o `.load`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Galera, primeiro peço desculpa pois o exemplo estava errada. O problema de fazer duas chamadas ao mesmo método é que eu estava utilizando o método `.on()` do `Jquery`, para o mesmo botão.

Exemplo

Menu.jsp:

```
<div>
    <div id="home">Home</div>
    <div id="contato">Contatos</div>
</div>
```

menu.js

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     $("#home").click(function(){
         //.dconteudo è uma div onde jogo as páginas que serão exibida no site 
         $(".dconteudo").load("home.jsp")
     });

     $("#contato").click(function(){
         //.dconteudo è uma div onde jogo as páginas que serão exibida no site 
         $(".dconteudo").load("contato.jsp")
     });
});
```

Home.jsp

```
....
<head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="home.js"></script>
</head>...
```

Contato.jsp

```
....
<head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="contato.js"></script>
</head>...
```

home.js

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('body').on('click', '#btnConfirmar', carregaFundo);
});

function carregaFundo(){
     $("#fundo").show(200);
}
```

contato.js

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('body').on('click', '#btnConfirmar', carregaFundo);
});

function carregaFundo(){
     $("#fundo").show(200);
}
```

Ou seja, o `.on()` coloca o evento duas vezes no Botão.

Obrigado.

Answer (score 2):

Você pode utilizar funções localizadas em variáveis e até poderia limpá-las (opcionalmente) antes de carregar o próximo arquivo js:

```
foo = function() { }
foo = undefined; // isso limpa a função... porém é opcional, a próxima linha faria isso
foo = function() { console.log("It works!"); }
foo();
```

Mas isto só iria te dar mais dor de cabeça, faça cada arquivo js com suas funções nomeadas unicamente, é um padrão em projetos pequenos e grandes, se for mais fácil utilize prefixos de funções em cada arquivo, assim você não perde:

```
function home_load() { }
function home_btn1Click() {  }

function contato_submitForm() { }
function contato_btn1Click() { }
```

> Lembre-se de carregar apenas os arquivos JS necessários em cada
>   página.

Outra sugestão:
Tente não replicar chamadas de funções, se `home` já faz, `contato` não deve fazer... deixe apenas as funções específicas na página contato